# Eclipse to wildfly in debug mode - deployment timeouts after few times

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I have a problem that after about 3 deployments from eclipse to wildfly - deployment times out.

**The odd thing is that when I deploy .war through management console everything is fine even when I run wildfly in debug mode, and does not get slower.**

Another odd thing is that it fails on the same step (Initilizing servlet) when the option "Deploy projects as compressed archives" is enabled but fails randomly when it's not enabled.

There are no classloader memory leaks and I removed all breakpoints, even tried it on different PC with same result. Im using Eclipse 2021-03 and wildfly 23.0.2.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

You did not describe which Eclipse plugin is used to connect to Wildfly.

If you are not already using the [JBoss Tools plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools), please take a look at
https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-wildfly-configuration and install and configure the plugin as described at the website.

If you are still using [JBoss Tools plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools) you could try following:

- Switch to an another JBoss tools plugin version and check if the problem still exists.
- Open [Get involved](https://tools.jboss.org/getinvolved/) JBoss page and report the issue
  *(here the direct link to [JBoss tools issue tracker](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE) )*
- Ask the question at the [JBoss tools community](https://tools.jboss.org/community/) - e.g. inside the user forum
- If none of the former steps did solve your poblem, you could still try out another eclipse plugin for EE respectively Wildfly on eclipse marketplace.